# Python - If statement: Elif or Else are not working for a password generating code

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to run this code without success. It is supposed to be a basic password generator that let you choose between generating a 20-characters one and a 8-char one.

Here is the code:

```
import random
def genpass():
    print('this is a password generator biiaatch!')

full_char_table = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~"
alpha_char_table = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"


scelta = input('choose a password: S = simple one/8 characters; D = difficult one/20 characters: ') 
x = 0
if scelta == "s" or "S":
    lenght = 8
    _type = alpha_char_table
    password = ""
        
    for x in range(int(lenght)):
        password = password + _type[int(random.randrange(len(_type)))]
        
        x += 1
    print('the password is: ' + password)    
elif scelta == "D" or "d":
    lenght2 = 20
    _type2 = full_char_table
    password2 = ""
        
    for x in range(int(lenght2)):
        password2 = password2 + _type2[int(random.randrange(len(_type2)))]
        
        x += 1
    print('the password is: ' + password2)
```

---

It generates only the 8-chars one, even if I digit D or d or whatever.
Does anybody know why it behaves like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 1):

As other people have pointed out, you are using the 'logical or' operator incorrectly, and have given you a solution. However, using an 'or' is unnecessary as you can just use the 'lower' (or 'upper') method, as it just converts a string to lowercase, of strings in this case. So it would look like:

```
if scelta.lower() == 's':
    #...
elif scelta.lower() == 'd':
    #...
else: # also include an else, in case input doesn't match any defined cases
    #...
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using the `or` operator is wrong. `or` is a logical operator which returns `True` if at least one of the operands is true. In your case, the `"S"` operand of the `or` operator *is* true, so the first branch of `if` is always chosen. (The same applies to the `"d"` operand of `elif` but the branch is never chosen because of the above reason.)

To look for both uppercase *or* lowercase letter, the (el)if commands should look like this:

```
if scelta == "s" or scelta == "S":
# ...
elif scelta == "D" or scelta == "d":
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the following lines to replace your if / elif statement:

```
if scelta == "s" or scelta == "S":
```

and

```
elif scelta == "D" or scelta == "d":
```

You haven't used the 'or' statement correctly, remember that each part of the if the statement is separate and you can't just use the variable again without defining it. :)

Good luck!